# Get array as response from Ajax request

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I use the following Ajax request to pass data:

```
var query = {   
 "username" : $('#username').val(),
 "email" : $('#email').val(), 
}

$.ajax({    
    type : "POST",  
    url : "system/process_registration.php",    
    data : query,   
    cache : false,  
    success : function(html) { 
        // output
        }
    });
```

My php-file (process-registration.php), in which the query is being processed, looks like this:

```
require_once 'db.php';

$username = $_REQUEST['username'];
$email = $_REQUEST['email'];

// Include new user into database
$db -> query("INSERT INTO users (username, email) VALUES ('$username', '$email');");

//Identify user id of this new user (maybe there is a faster way???)
$results = $db -> query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username'");
while ($result = $results->fetch_assoc()) {
    $user_id = $result['id'];
}

// My output?
```

Now comes my question: How can I tell the Ajax command / the PHP script to return as a result two elements:

- a HTML message: `<p>You have registered successfully</p>`
- the $user_id that I have identified via the loop above

I need the user_id, because in the frontend I want to include it as a GET parameter into the href of the button "Go to admin area" that will appear AFTER the Ajax request will be completed.

Comment: try returning JSON object , containing both the information ..

Comment: You can return the string delimited by some character or string and then split it into an array.

Comment: Does anyone of you have a code suggestion?

Comment: Why should you return the html-message? Return 0 or a negative number if not succesfull, any number above 0 is succesfull and the id-number. So you have only the id to deal with, the message you can add in javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$response = array('user_id'=>$user_id,'message'=>'Success - user created');
echo json_encode($response);
```

This will give return a json object that you can access in JS.

```
$.ajax({    
    type : "POST",  
    url : "system/process_registration.php",    
    data : query,   
    cache : false,
    dataType: 'json',  
    success : function(html) { 
        // output - do something with the response
        console.log(html.user_id);
        console.log(html.message); 
        }
    });
```

Comment: this comes at the end of my php script, I guess? thanks. so what would I need to put into the ajax-success-function in my frontend?

Comment: updated the answer, you will need of course to substitute your data in the $repsonse array and and do what ever action you want in the success callback.

Comment: I just tried the following code in my php-script: $response = array('message_success'=>"You have been registered successfully",'user_id'=>$user_id);
echo json_encode($response); And in my ajax function I wrote the same as you suggested. But both results are displayed as "undefined" in my console.....

Comment: add `dataType: 'json'` as I updated in the answer. Also can you print the response of the ajax request so I can tell if there is something wrong

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be better to change the array in string by putting a special character(I use % or #)between different values. In your case just echo '

You have registered successfully

%'.$user_id ;. Now explode the response string and use both.

Comment: This practice is not quite ok, since, sometimes you'll split the message in an incorrect place. It is best to send JSON, as it can be easily parsed on the client side.